# Magento2 custom price render on product page

Tags: magento2

How to format the product view page price differently from the one from category page ( and possible others ) ?

If I change in my child theme the:

`app/design/frontend/VENDOR/my_theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

The price is being changed on both pages (category and product);

I have tried several approaches but it seems that this price rendering mechanism is complicated as hell in Magento2.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Guess that it is a bit late to pick this question back up but if you have a layout.xml defined for the product view page and in Magento source code it has a product render template as a child of the element then you can just override this child with your custom render template

Comment: Otehrwise if you are struggling with price rendering in general you should give some code in your question or at least exactly what you want to happen (before & after)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
try {
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $request = $objectManager->get(‘Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context’)->getRequest();
  $currentPageXML = $request->getFullActionName();
  echo $currentPageXML; //catalog_product_view is product detail page controller action
} catch (Exception $e) {}
?>
```

The above code will help you get the current area of the environment being accessed, and then you can apply a logic

```
if ($currentPageXML=="catalog_product_view") {
  // render my custom need
} else {
  // keep the actual code intact.
}
```

You are facing a problem because same `phtml` file is being used by both the catalog and product page, so a change in this file will be reflected everywhere.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Using this kind of code is really error prone. It's important to understand the way price rendering works and properly make your changes instead of a "quick fix" that easily breaks.